# Simple but specific array compiling error (C)

Tags: arrays, c, initialization, declaration, variable-length-array

This is what I write:

```
   const int MAX=100;

   int main (){
       int notas [MAX]={0};
```

The compiler says the following:

> [Error] variable-sized object may not be initialized
> [Warning] excess elements in array initializer

When I write `MAX` with `#define MAX 100`, it works. But I don´t understand what's the matter with doing it this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the `const` in the declaration

```
const int MAX = 100;
```

`MAX` is not a *constant expression* (i.e., something whose value is known at compile time).  Its value isn't known until *run time*, so the declaration of `notas` is treated as a variable-length array declaration, and a VLA declaration may not have an initializer (nor may a VLA be declared at file scope, nor may it be a member of a `struct` or `union` type).

With the preprocessor macro

```
#define MAX 100
```

all instances of the symbol `MAX` are replaced with the literal `100` after preprocessing, so it's effectively the same as writing

```
int notas[100] = {0};
```

which is why using the preprocessor macro works.

Answer (score 6):

In this case

```
 const int MAX=100;
```

does not create a compile time constant, so the array is treated as [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). By definition, VLAs can not be initialised, hence the error.

On the other hand, `#define MAX 100` is a pre-processor macro, and based on the textual replacement property, it results in a compile time constant value of `100`, then the array is not a VLA and can be initialized as per the initialization rules.

Answer (score 3):

This

```
   const int MAX=100;
int main (){
   int notas [MAX]={0};
```

is a declaration of a variable length array the size of which is determined at run-time because the declaration of the variable MAX is not a compile-time constant in C. Such arrays may not be initialized in declarations.

From the C Standard (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 3 The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of
> unknown size or a complete object type that is not a variable length
> array type.

So you could write for example

```
   const int MAX=100;
int main (){
   int notas [MAX];
   memset( notas, 0, MAX * sizeof( int ) );
```

Otherwise you could use a compile time constant like

```
   enum { MAX=100 };
int main (){
   int notas [MAX]={0};
```